# Unknown methode is showing when calling a methode in controller ,which is present in model of that controller in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am new to cakephp 3.2
I have saved data by calling model in cakephp 2X version in this way.

```
 $this->Schools->add_school($schools);
```

I have used the same in 3x,but it not working showing 
Unknown method "add_school"

I have defined the function in model also

below is model code School.php

School.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;



class School extends Entity
{

      public function add_school($schools) {
        echo "hii";exit;
    }
}
```

error is showing 
Unknown method "add_school" 
Please suggest me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ***Typo*** Your Schools should be School

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the docs a little more closely, you are mixing up entities and tables. The former represent data, and the latter are used for interacting with the database.

Your custom method should go into your `SchoolsTable` class (in `src/Model/Table`), then, given that `$this->Schools` exists (you may need to use `$this->loadModel('Schools'))`, you can call your method via that reference.

See

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html)**

Answer (score -1):

your writing code is right becouse your code have mistek which is 
yes used this only one mistek "s"

```
$this->School->add_school($schools);
```